# How can i change the app icon while building in Rhomobile

Tags: iphone, xcode, rhomobile

I followed the docs for creating the ios application using Rhomobile.

I have all the icon images placed inside icon folder.
But after opening the application in xcode, it shows the rhomobile default icon.

How and where can i change the icon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you runs the command to create the xcode project, in your rhodes folder, one `icon.png` image is generated. You need to replace that image with yours.

Path : `<rhodes_path>/platform/iphone/icon.png`

Then you can open the xcode and start building the app.

Answer (score 2):

click on your project name go to TARGETS>>summary>>App icon.
 Now drag your icon.